# DefinitelyTyped Typescript Definition doesn't recognize mongoose dependencies

Tags: mongodb, typescript, mongoose, definitelytyped

I'm using TypeScript, Angular 2 and mongoose.  I installed mongoose using NPM:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.6",
    "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "mongoose": "^4.6.0",
    "morgan": "^1.7.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.11",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "typescript": "^2.0.0",
    "typings": "^1.3.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jasmine-core": "^2.5.1",
    "karma": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2"
  }
```

Of course, mongoose installs mongodb as a dependency. I then installed the mongoose DefintielyTyped definitions using command `typipngs install dt~mongoose --global --save.` That installs the mongoose index file:

```
// Generated by typings
// Source: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/51c51f03549a63f8791865bf26480947e22f4902/mongoose/mongoose.d.ts
declare module "mongoose" {
  import events = require('events');
  import mongodb = require('mongodb');
  import stream = require('stream');
  import mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

etc., etc. When I run `tsc`, I get the following error: `typings/globals/mongoose/index.d.ts(5,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'mongodb'`.  It doesn't feel right to `npm install mongodb --save` since it is already installed with mongoose.

What is the right way of fixing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not asking you to install the module, it's asking you to install the typings for `mongodb`.  Typings by default do not install dependency typings.  So you have to go through and install each dependencies manually.

Specifically for Mongoose, you are going to need the typings for `mongodb`, `mpromise` and `mongoose-promise` (I think that's all of them).

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Is there a better way I can write my typings.json to better convey the fact that mongodb is a mongoose dependency?

Comment: Nothing that I am aware of